# Ctrl + c / Ctrl + v with memory effect

Tags: python, hotkeys, pynput

I think, that it would sometimes greatly improve your workflow, if you
could `ctrl + c` (copy) in a series.

That means, that when pressing `ctrl +c` is pressed, the content is stored in the memory
until `ctrl + v` releases all the strings in memory. (Let's assume at the beginning, I only copy strings).

I would like to use `pynput` but any other solution is appreciated as well and this is how far I got:

```py
from pynput import keyboard

current = set()


class memory_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.memory = []
        return None
    def add_element(self,element):
        self.memory.append(element)
    def clear_memory(self):
        self.memory = []

memory = memory_class()


def execute():
    print("Hello ! C has been pressed.")
    memory.add_element("Hello")

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

# The key combination to check
COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.KeyCode(char='c')},
    #{keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='A')}
]

with keyboard.Listener(on_press = on_press, on_release = on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

- How do I access the text that is usually copied when using `ctrl + c`. The function
  `on_press` always only depend on the key that has been pressed.
- How do I implement another method `ctrl + v` that pastes all the content from the memory and deletes it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you use tkinter

```
Tk().clipboard_get()
```

Or use library, pyperclip

```
import pyperclip as pc
  
number = 100
  
# copying text to clipboard
pc.copy(number)
  
# pasting the text from clipboard
text = pc.paste()
  
print(text)
```